# Payment Options not appearing in Magento

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.5

a bit of a funny one for you this afternoon.

This is in Magento 1.5.1.0...

Essentially, my website sells products that are free (£0.00) however the customer has to pay for delivery. The problem that I’m having, is that at checkout, the Payment Methods simply doesn’t load whenever the basket sub total is 0. Even when the Grand Total with Shipping is an amount.

I’m running One Step Checkout, however it doesn’t work on the default One Page Checkout either.

I’ve tried everything, and I’m certain that it’s not got anything to do with the Payment Gateways that I’m using.

I tried the same thing on another site of mine, that’s running 1.4 and it works fine on there?

You can see a screenshot of the page with the problem [here...](http://www.magentocommerce.com/?ACT=25&fid=10&aid=27405_LVtppMnspzJIL4cQWGBh&board_id=1)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about Magento might be some kind of rule running.But in general this is not a typical E-commerce platform behaviou

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have: "Zero Subtotal Checkout" enabled under: System -> Configuration -> Payment Methods.

Subtotal is pre shipping, tax and discounts, this payment option exists specifically for your circumstance.